# Stop click event on input field within dropdown menu (AngularJS filter element)

Tags: angularjs, drop-down-menu, angularjs-ng-repeat, preventdefault

I've got a Dropdown Menu with an input field to search my li elements. The problem is: Whenever I click into the input field to put in my search query, a click event happens and the dropdown menu disappears.

**I tried preventDefault on the input field, but it didn't work. How can I stop the behaviour?**

Here's a Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/SlbWZ5Bh62MDKWViUsMr

Here's my markup (It's the input with the ng-model="customerFilter"):

```
<div class="button">
  <a class="btn btn-large grey dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
    Organisation
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu grey" >
    <input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter">
    <li ng-repeat="customer in customers | filter:customerFilter | orderBy:sortorder" ng-click="addCardGrey(customer)">{{ customer.name }}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: You probably want to take a look at the angularui project, believe it'll be easier than trying to wrap up the bootstrap code yourself.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`preventDefault` stops the default action the browser makes on that event.

What you want to use is `stopPropagation`, which stops the event from bubbling up the event chain.

You can for example use it in a directive like this:

Code:

```
.directive('myInput', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            element.bind('click', function (event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Markup:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="customerFilter" my-input>
```

Comment: Awesome! Exactly, what I needed, tasseKATT! :) Thank you so much!